# Functional equation involving product and convolution

Tags: functional-equations, convolution

Can the following functional equation be solved for H(x) in terms of F(x)?
$$
x \cdot H(x) = [F * H](x)
$$
where $*$ denotes convolution.

Of ancillary interest, can anything be said about the solution to function equations which mix multiplication and convolution of the form: (for given F,G)
$$
G(x) \cdot H(x) = [F * H](x)
$$

The main equation arises from attempting to describe the fourier transform of the following $h(x)$ in terms of the transform of $f(x)$.
$$h(x) = \exp \left ( i \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt \right )$$

Comment: In k space you get a differential equation since $x$ transforms to $i\partial_k$

Comment: Yes, and solving the diffy Q just gives the equation at the bottom of the post.

Comment: soooo... problem solved?

Comment: the question is whether you can express H in terms of F directly, as opposed to expressing the fourier transform of H in terms of the fourier transform of F.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me.  I don't see the distinction.

Comment: I'm looking for a kind of function composition rule for fourier transforms, for the specific function at the bottom. Much like how's there's a product rule and differentiation rule.